# what these buzz words actually stand for?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, m2e

**m2e** :- i know its maven 2 eclipse but 2 stands for maven version 2 or English literal "to" ?

**j2ee** :-  java 2 enterprise edition similarly  2 stands for java version 2 or English literal "to" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are "version" numbers. J2EE is no longer used, it's Java EE.

I suspect M2E was originally meaning Maven 2, but then evolved to a name.

Comment: version numbers of maven and java. Is it ? If yes i am using maven 3 and java 6, is it not a bad practice to use version in these nomenclature ?

Comment: Actually M2E might be just a name. Like I said, J2EE isn't used anymore. Don't you have bigger problems than the number `2` in some names?

Answer (score -1):

It stands for Magento to eBay.  This is a software owned by eBay as a plugin for Magento

or Maven Integration Elipse is something else.